# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Using IBInspectable

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, ibinspectable

I am trying to use `IBInspectable` to add borders to my views.

```
extension UIView {

    private func getBorder(integer: Int) -> UIRectEdge {
        if integer == 1 {
            return .top
        } else if integer == 2 {
            return .left
        } else if integer == 3 {
            return .right
        } else if integer == 4 {
            return .bottom
        }
        return .all

    }

    @IBInspectable var border: Int? {
        get {
            return self.border
        }
        set (value) {
            self.border = value
            for v in addBorder(edges: self.getBorder(integer: self.border!)) {
                self.addSubview(v)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return self.borderColor
        }
        set (value) {
            self.borderColor = value //EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
            for v in addBorder(edges: self.getBorder(integer: self.border!), color: borderColor!) {
                self.addSubview(v)
            }
        }
    }

    private func addBorder(edges: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor = UIColor.white, thickness: CGFloat = 1) -> [UIView] {
        ...
    }
}
```

The crash occurs on the line `self.borderColor = value` (in the `set` for the `borderColor`).

All it says in the debug log is `(lldb)`. The crash itself says:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff53cc5fe8)

Here is my storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion there, that is causing the crash. Basically  within the setter of `borderColor` you're calling the setter for the same property, resulting the infinite recursion.

This happens because class extensions are not allowed to have stored properties, so Swift doesn't generate a backstore for your property, instead it treats it like a computed property, and calls the setter whenever you try to set the property.

There are two solutions that I can think of at this time, that will solve your problem:

1. Subclass UIView, add the two properties there, update the class in IB to match the name of your new class.
2. Use associated objects in your `UIView` accessors (`objc_setAssociatedObject()`/ `objc_getAssociatedObject()`) instead of direct iVar reference. You will not need to subclass and to update your xibs, however this solution is a little bit messier than the first one.